# Timeout while using table valued parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I'm trying to find the cause for this error while calling a stored proc with a table valued parameter:

> Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

My objective is to load sanitized data from a 3rd party app into a data-warehousey location for in-house apps to consume. I don't have an "updated" flag in the source, so I'm using a data flow to push all of the data into a recordset, then firing a script task to call a `MERGE` proc with TVP.

I've used this pattern successfully several times, but this data set is by far the largest--over 1m rows (though not terribly wide). I can always truncate and reload the table every time within an acceptable time frame, but that just seems awfully wasteful on I/O.

I looked at the settings in the ADO.NET connection, but the timeouts there don't seem like they should apply. I'm considering slicing the recordset into smaller chunks and looping over the proc, but without a better understanding of the problem, I suspect that would just cause problems when the data set grows enough to make the chunks fail.

Proc:

```
alter proc [sis].[Attendance_Merge]
    @data sisAttendance readonly
    as begin
if object_id('tempdb..#data') is not null drop table #data;
create table #data (
    [SchoolYear] smallint not null,
    [Student] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Period] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL,
    [Reason] [varchar] (32) NOT NULL,
    [Funding] [varchar] (1) NOT NULL,
    [StateReported] [varchar] (1) NOT null,
    [rn] int not null
    primary key clustered (SchoolYear,Student,[Date],Period,rn)
    );
insert into #data
select
    *
    ,rn = row_number() over(
        partition by
            SchoolYear
            ,Student
            ,[Date]
            ,Period
        order by
            Student
        )
    from @data
    ;
with att as (
    select
        *
        ,rn = row_number() over(
            partition by
                SchoolYear
                ,Student
                ,[Date]
                ,Period
            order by
                Student
            )
        from sis.Attendance
    )
merge into att t
    using #data s
        on t.SchoolYear = s.SchoolYear
        and t.Student = s.Student
        and t.[Date] = s.[Date]
        and t.Period = s.Period
        and t.rn = s.rn
    when matched
            and (t.Reason <> s.Reason
                or t.Funding <> s.Funding
                or t.StateReported <> s.StateReported
                )
        then update set 
            t.Reason = s.Reason
            ,t.Funding = s.Funding
            ,t.StateReported = s.StateReported
    when not matched by target
        then insert (
            SchoolYear
            ,Student
            ,[Date]
            ,Period
            ,Reason
            ,Funding
            ,StateReported
            )
        values (
            s.SchoolYear
            ,s.Student
            ,s.[Date]
            ,s.Period
            ,s.Reason
            ,s.Funding
            ,s.StateReported
            )
    when not matched by source
        then delete
    ;
end
```

Comment: You're probably getting a plan optimised for a single row. Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: The timeout is going to be enforced by `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`.  It defaults to 30 seconds.  This is a client-side enforcement.  Whereas there is a good chance your T-SQL code may not be optimal, the root of the actual timeout isn't there.

Comment: @Martin -- Didn't change anything, but got me looking more at the proc itself. I was dumping the TVP into a temp table immediately, then doing the merge. Thinking an index might help, I added a clustered PK constraint, but also no change. Now I'm starting to think that dumping 1m rows into a temp table isn't saving any I/O over rewriting the table...maybe I'm coming at this all wrong

Comment: @Thomas -- That's what I was looking for! I'd found references to that attached to a connection string, but not to the SqlCommand, and I didn't make the connection. `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;` let it complete successfully! Now to figure out if this was a good idea to begin with...

Comment: Ah I assumed you were using the TVP directly in the merge. If you are looking for suggestions to speed things up then post the procedure and the execution plan.

Comment: @SQLFox Raising the `CommandTimeout` isn't necessarily a bad thing.  If you have a well-tuned query that is simply taking greater than 30 seconds (i.e. reporting, etc.) then you'll have to mold that timeout value.  And I think what you were initially changing was the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` value.  Although easily confused, two very different timeouts affecting different parts of the data retrieval process.

Comment: I haven't studied the code in depth but why the #temp table? Why not just use the TVP as the source for the MERGE? Does the definition of the TVP include a PK constraint? Also, my typical disclaimer, [please MERGE with caution](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: I started using the #temp with this pattern (unless the data set is fairly small) after starting to run into performance issues using large table variables. I'm operating under an assumption that a TVP is equivalent to a table variable inside of a proc--but even so, it may well be an overreaction to be using the #temp without specific indication to need it in this circumstance. There is no PK on the TVP (it isn't by definition unique--but I could move the row_number upstream to make it so).

Comment: Re: MERGE -- I really want MERGE to work well/reliably. I've gotten comfortable with the syntax and find it convenient for my most common tasks--especially when I'm dumping the output to a log table. Most of the issues I've read about seem to be with features we don't make heavy use of (indexed views, filtered indexes, triggers), so I haven't abandoned it (for this environment at least)--though I realize it may bite me later.

Comment: @SQLFox - That was why my suggestion to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. You might find that gives an OK plan using the TVP directly without the need for an intermediate step of loading the `#temp` table. Though would be useful to get an idea of how long each step in the process is taking.